# One CD in Two-CD Cluster Not Writing Logs

Tags: logging, content-delivery, load-balancer

I have a CD environment in a two-CD cluster running Sitecore 8.1u2, and today I noticed that my CD2 environment is not writing to its logs, even though it is running exactly as expected.

I verified the following:

- CD1 and the CM are all writing to their logs, as expected
- The site is still running and I do not have any relevant errors in the Event Viewer
- Permissions have been assigned correctly (triple-checked and had a peer verify, as well)

**UPDATE**

- The Data folder is configured correctly and is not being overridden *(in response to @OwenNiblock's comments)*
- The `LogFileAppender` is set to the correct path *(in response to @DerekC's answer)*

I feel like I'm going crazy and that there is something ridiculously simple that I'm missing. Does anyone know what could cause logs to suddenly stop writing without error, and know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked "showconfig" to see if the data directory location is being overridden somewhere?

Comment: Against all odds, but is there any traffic on CD2?

Comment: I did check, and the Data directory is specified correctly and not overridden. I will update the OP with that check @OwenNiblock. That's still a good catch ;)

Comment: @ThomasD there is no "real" traffic at present. I am currently getting these environments ready for production. However, I am actively testing, so if traffic from me, alone, counts....

Comment: You could try to turn on log4net internal logging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2263359/6144330

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but does your AppPool have permission to write to the data folder?

Comment: Permissions all verified and accounted for, @PeteNavarra

Comment: Do any ASP.NET errors show up in the Event Log?

Comment: @Gatogordo - I'll give that a shot. I like the whole "did you try turning it off and back on again" troubleshooting step. To save time, I'm going to check and see if there is a way I can do that in an ASPX file or two, so I don't have to do a full deployment

Comment: @PeteNavarra not seeing any errors :/

Comment: How are you testing traffic? Are you going through a load balancer to the delivery servers or hitting them directly? If through a load balancer check that it doesn't have sticky sessions or similar on. Try hitting the server directly from the box.

Comment: @RichardSeal what I meant is that there really isn't any traffic yet. I just set the servers up and have just pinged pages to bring up the site and make sure that it loads so I can debug any environment issues in the logs before passing the URLs off to the team and such.

Comment: Yeah, making assumptions (per Rich's comment) that you are locally hitting the site, I would have to start seeing configs, screen shots of the folder structure, app pool settings, and portions of the showconfig.aspx in order to provide help here. This is clearly.. a permissions/configuration/disk issue.. if it's not creating logs.

Comment: @Gatogordo for the win! I searched for "reset log4net sitecore" and found a John West post that linked to an old SDN article called "Wake up log files". Apparently this is a known issue. All I had to do was create the described ASPX and hit it and the logs started writing again. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gatogordo's "try turning it off and back on" suggestion did the trick. I found John West's [All About Logging with Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-logging-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) blog post, which led me to an old SDN article, aptly named [Wake up log files](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Wake%20up%20log%20files.aspx).

The article poses the following problem:

> Occasionally after application restart log files are not working. How can I fix this without making a second restart?

As a solution, the article instructs you to create an ASPX file with the following contents:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.LogManager.ResetConfiguration();
        log4net.Config.DOMConfigurator.Configure();
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Log wake up</title>
</head>
<body>
Done.
</body>
</html>
```

What this is doing is reloading the log4net configuration, essentially *turning it off and back on again.*

I added this to my site root, hit it from the browser and behold! I had log files! Thanks @Gatogordo!

Answer (score 1):

Some other things worth checking in your configs via /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx:

Data Folder is set properly:

```xml
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sxa82\Data"/>
```

Check the appender node to make sure the path is correctly compiling to the right path:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
 <file value="C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sxa82\\Data/logs/log.{date}.txt"/>
 <appendToFile value="true"/>
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n"/>
 </layout>
 <encoding value="utf-8"/>
</appender>
```

Comment: Ah, disregard. Just saw you edited and checked it. Still might be worth checking the appender.

Comment: All checked and accounted for, but still +1 because this might help others :)